# Cross-thread operation not valid (invoke required) for webform

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I understand how the backgroundworker or threads are unable to update controls if not declared on the same level etc and how to create delegates to invoke the control event but how does one do this with web forms. Is there a similar method or function to prevent the cross thread operation not valid error on web forms?

Answer (score 1):

in webforms it has no sense. when you do some operations on webform nothing actually takes place. this values are meaningful when controls are rendered, and it takes place after custom code is executed.

Comment: So I guess trying to use a progress bar on a web form and have it updated by the background worker thread wont work, right? thanks